# Is it possible to integrate first data payment integration in phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, firstdata

I'm currently developing a `phongap` application in `iOS` with payment processs. For that payment process i have integrated `Paypal` payment gateway. Now my requirement is payment with `firstData`. I don't know if any SDK is available for this, also what other type of payment should be possible to integrate with `phonegap` ?

Thanks